# Faster aggregate multiple columns

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

I have following function which runs 100s of times. This aggregation is the bottleneck in my code. Is it possible to make is faster with just using data.table or rewrite this function using rcpp?

```
  logit.gr <- function(DT){
    temp1 <- DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) col1*sum(y*(x - sum(x*exp(col2))))), by = .(main_idx), .SDcols = c('col3','col4')]
    return(-colSums(temp1[, c('col3','col4'), with = F]))
  }
```

where DT is

```
DT <- data.table(main_idx = c(rep('A',4), rep('B', 5)), col1 = runif(9), col2 = -2+runif(9), col3 = 1+runif(9), col4 = 1+runif(9), y = runif(9))
```

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Thank you. I just did it

Comment: should it be `col3*sum(y*(x - sum(x*exp(col4)))))` instead of this `col1*sum(y*(x - sum(x*exp(col2)))))`

Comment: Where are you using `theta` in your logic?

Comment: I was calling another function inside this function. I removed it since it was not the bottleneck. Forgot to remove theta.

Comment: @Sathish for the purpose of making it faster it does not matter which columns do you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think away to optimize is:

> 1. `sum` should be added in function used in `lapply` itself. It will result in to only 1 row per `main_idx` in resultant `data.table`.
> 2. chain of `[` operator should be used to `sum` columns `col3` and `col4`.

```
library(data.table)
DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(col1*sum(y*(x - sum(x*exp(col2)))))), 
   by = .(main_idx), .SDcols = c('col3','col4')][
         ,.(col3 = -sum(col3), col4 = -sum(col4))]
#Result
#     col3      col4 
#0.7575290 0.2423651
```

**Data:**

```
DT <- data.table(main_idx = c(rep('A',4), rep('B', 5)), 
              col1 = runif(9), col2 = -2+runif(9), 
              col3 = 1+runif(9), col4 = 1+runif(9), y = runif(9))
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I may have dynamic number of columns to aggregate (e.g. right now I have just col3, col4. I can also have col5, col6...)

Comment: Nevermind. I can use .SD to do the dynamic number of columns

Comment: That's fine. All you need to vary is `.SDcols`. May be in 2nd `[` operator just exclude `main_idx` and get the `sum`. You can set the column name anyway.

Comment: @deepAgrawal exactly.

Comment: But still the major computation is being done in the lapply group by part. Is there a way to make that faster?

Comment: Yes. It will switch to `lapply` context but only once per column.